# jQuery fadeToggle starts from hidden instead of visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that on click of my div text appeard. But unfortunently it's hidding in first click and in second click it gets visible. What's wrong?

```
$('#fPaperCirclePic').on('click', function () {
    $('#fPaperCircleText, #isargebla, #moq10k').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#fPaperCircleText, #isargebla, #moq10k').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/qunebebaxu/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Why are you setting the css visibility first?

Comment: because in css I have visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line from js

```
$('#fPaperCircleText, #isargebla, #moq10k').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

and add `display:none` in `css` replacing it `visibility:hidden`

`fadeToggle` toggles `display` property

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fPaperCirclePic').on('click', function() {
    $('#fPaperCircleText, #isargebla, #moq10k').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  });
});
```

```css
#fPaperCircleText,
#isargebla,
#moq10k {
  display: none;
}
#fPaperCirclePic {
  background: red no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#fPaperCircleText {} #isargebla {
  font-size: 19px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#moq10k {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fPaperCirclePic"></div>
<span id="fPaperCircleText">                     
asdasasd <br />დამოუკიდებელი სისტემა</span>
<span id="isargebla">ისარგებლა</span>
<span id="moq10k">  <h3>10 000</h3> -ზე მეტმა მოქალაქემ </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your css to

```
#fPaperCircleText, #isargebla, #moq10k {
    display: none;
 }
```

And remove your css change from your javascript.

```
$('#fPaperCirclePic').on('click', function () {
    $('#fPaperCircleText, #isargebla, #moq10k').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change visibility:hidden with display:none